# Hook for specific wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know how to add a specific action for a specific page. I'm creating a new plugin that have to run only on a new page, specially created. I know how to run it in general, but i don't know how to make it run only on a specific page id.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) like this:

```
add_action( 'my_hook', 'custom_my_hook' );
function custom_my_hook() {
    if ( is_page( 123 ) ) { // replace 123 with your page id
        // only execute on page 123
    }
}
```